# my query produces error “ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended” in C++

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, ora-00933

Here is my query

```
    csQuery.Format (_T ("INSERT INTO EFFECTS 
        (EFFECT_NM,EFFECT_VALUE_NUM,EFFECT_DIR_NM,PROJECT_ID_SQ) 
        SELECT '%s',%f,'%s',STACK_GAP.PROJECT_ID_SQ 
        where PROJECT.PROJECT_NM = '%s'"),TDName,TDvalue,TTDdirection,csProjectName);
```

I am getting SQL command not properly ended error while i execute this query in C++ but it works correctly in PL\SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a semicolon after your `INSERT` query, I believe.

```
csQuery.Format (_T ("INSERT INTO EFFECTS(EFFECT_NM,EFFECT_VALUE_NUM,EFFECT_DIR_NM,PROJECT_ID_SQ) SELECT '%s',%f,'%s',STACK_GAP.PROJECT_ID_SQ where PROJECT.PROJECT_NM = '%s';"),TDName,TDvalue,TTDdirection,csProjectName);
```